# Unable to get aspnet core api naming to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a client controller that is called "ClientController".  The start of the controller is as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ClientController : Controller
```

The first httpget method works like this - naming etc just a "Get":

```
    public IActionResult Get()
    {...
```

..and it does indeed work when I use Postman with a call:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/Client
```

However, If I change the name to Index and name it Index like so:

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {...
        return new OkObjectResult(some object)
    }
```

and I use Postman again to call it this time explicitly:

```
    http://localhost:5001/api/Client/Index
```

I get a 404 status..  - Not found..

I have looked around for some answers on this but its a bit light on for ASPNET Core examples for API and naming conventions..

How do you name an IActionResult API method (via connotations) and call it correctly (eg URL structure)? A little direction on correct convention would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
    [HttpGet("Index",Name = "Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {...
        return new OkObjectResult(some object)
    }
```

More detail is given on this link. Please check it out

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Comment: Winner! Used "http://localhost:5001/api/Client/Index" and it stopped at the breakpoint... excellent. upvoted.